# Strange occurrence with character creation in Inform 7

Tags: inform7

Okay, so I'm following the documentation as much as is convenient to allow the player to set a name and gender for their character but there's one problem. This doesn't actually affect gameplay whatsoever (as far as I have seen) but since adding in the gender part a 'That's not a verb I recognise' message shows up for seemingly no reason as soon as the player types in his/her name. This did not happen before I added in the gender selection.

Code:

```
The player's forename is an indexed text that varies. The player's full name is an indexed text that varies.

When play begins:
    now the command prompt is "What is your name? > ".

To decide whether collecting names:
    if the command prompt is "What is your name? > ", yes;
    no.

After reading a command when collecting names:
    now the player's full name is "[the player's command in title case]";
    now the player's forename is word number 1 in the player's full name;
    now the command prompt is "Are you male or female? > ".

Gender is a kind of value. The genders are masculine, feminine, and unknown. Understand "male", "man", "boy" or "m" as masculine. Understand "female", "woman", "girl" or "f" as feminine.

A person has a gender. The gender of the player is unknown.

To decide whether the gender of the player is unknown:
    if the command prompt is "Are you male or female? > ", yes;
    no.

After reading a command when the gender of the player is unknown:
    if the player's command includes "[gender]":
        now the gender of the player is the gender understood;
        if the gender of the player is masculine, now the player is male;
        if the gender of the player is feminine, now the player is female;
        now the command prompt is "> ";
        say "Thank you, [player's forename].[paragraph break]";
        say "[banner text]";
        move the player to the bed;
        reject the player's command.

Instead of looking when collecting names: do nothing.
Rule for printing the banner text when collecting names: do nothing.
Rule for constructing the status line when collecting names: do nothing.
Instead of looking when the gender of the player is unknown: do nothing.
Rule for printing the banner text when the gender of the player is unknown: do nothing.
Rule for constructing the status line when the gender of the player is unknown: do nothing.
```

Sorry if this is a lot of code ^.^'

Again, this hasn't affected functionality but having that message pop up is just unsightly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that even though you're accessing the text typed in the first After reading a command rule, you're not telling the game to not go and parse what they typed as well.

I'd recommend you just use the extension [Question by Michael Callaghan](http://inform7.com/extensions/Michael%20Callaghan/Questions/index.html) instead.